# Graph of quadratic $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ when $a$ is fixed and $b,c$ are varied

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I noticed a small thing while [playing with the graph of quadratic](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qn7iykhzq1).
$$ax^2+bx+c = a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 + c - a\left(\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2$$

Clearly $b,c$ only determine how the vertex of the graph changes, not the shape of the graph; that is, as $b,c$ are varied, the graph just translates without changing its shape.

This means adding a linear function $bx+c$ to a quadratic doesn't change its shape! This makes sense from above crude manipulation of the equation but I'm wondering if *there is a more satisfying way to see this, perhaps geometry/calculus*?

Comment: This will arise with any curve of equation $y=f(x)$, when you turn it to $y=f(x-X)+Y$: the graph translates by $(X,Y)$. When $f$ is $ax^2$, the nonlinear term remains $ax^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Given

$$y=ax^2+bx+c$$

by a translation $y=Y+A$ and $x=X+B$ we obtain

$$Y+A=a(X+B)^2+b(X+B)+c$$

$$Y=aX^2+\overbrace{(2aB+b)}^{\beta}X+\overbrace{aB^2+bB+c-A}^{\gamma}$$

> $$Y=aX^2+\beta X+\gamma$$

which has the same shape.

We can also go backward and show that adding a linear term corresponds to a translation, therefore shape doesn't change.

Refer also to the related

- [Related to parabola](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2539327/505767)

Comment: If I understand correctly,  $B, A$ can be *uniquely* determined from the given quadratic: $B = \frac{\beta - b}{2a}, A = aB^2 + bB+c-\gamma$. I don't see right away why this fails for a cubic like $ax^3+bx+c$ ? I know the shape changes as $b,c$ are varied for cubic, but I don't know why.. something to think later(for me). Thank you so much for the awesome answer:)

Comment: @across For a cubic the $ax^3$ term gives $a(X+B)^3=aX^3+3aBX^2+\ldots$. Therefore in general we also need to add quadratic terms to have the same shape. You are welcome! Bye